# Multiprocessing web scraping making script getting stuck

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am using Python multiprocessing to spawn multiple processes to scrape 5 URLs at a time. I am using proxies as well. After some X period of time script just stops working, it just gets stuck, with no error or anything. I am already using the timeout option in `requests` so definitely, timeout is not the issue either. I am storing data in DB and max 2 DB connections are getting initiated.

I enabled logging but no use as nothing there either.

Any idea what's going wrong?

I also ran the script without proxies and it seemed to work but I am not certain as I am still testing. I am not sure whether it is a multiprocessing issue, idleness of the system, or something else.

This is how I am making requests

```
def create_request(url, headers={}):
    r = None
    try:
        proxies = {
            'http': 'http://1.2.3.4:13010',
            # 'https': 'http://11.2.3.4:13010',
        }

        with requests.Session() as s:
            retries = Retry(total=5, backoff_factor=1, status_forcelist=[502, 503, 504, 429])
            s.mount('http://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

            # r = s.get(url, proxies=proxies, timeout=30, headers=headers)
            r = s.get(url, timeout=30, headers=headers)
            print('Status Code = ', r.status_code)
    except Exception as ex:
        crash_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")
        crash_string = "".join(traceback.format_exception(etype=type(ex), value=ex, tb=ex.__traceback__))
        exception_string = '[' + crash_date + '] - ' + crash_string + '\n'
        print(exception_string)
    finally:
        return r
```

**Update**

Code snippets for multiprocessing and the main function

```
connection = get_connection(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME)
    while True:
        print('Getting Links')
        logging.info('Getting Links')
        links = get_links(LIMIT)
        if len(links) == 0:
            break
        if len(links) > 0:
            with Pool(POOL_COUNT) as p:
                result = p.map(parse, links)

        sleep(5)
```

and

```
def parse(url):
    try:
        sleep(3)
        print('Connecting...', url)
        logging.info('Connecting...' + url)

        # Randomize the user agent
        user_agent = get_random_user_agent(user_agents)
        user_agent = user_agent.rstrip('\n')

        if 'linux' in user_agent.lower():
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'Linux'
        elif 'mac os x' in user_agent.lower():
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'macOS'
        else:
            sec_ch_ua_platform = 'Windows'

        print('User Agent = ', user_agent)
        logging.info('User Agent = ' + user_agent)

        headers = {
            'authority': 'www.etsy.com',
            'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
            'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ur;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh;q=0.6',
            'cache-control': 'no-cache',
            'dnt': '1',
            'pragma': 'no-cache',
            'sec-ch-ua': '".Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="103", "Chromium";v="103"',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"{}"'.format(sec_ch_ua_platform),
            'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
            'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
            'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
            'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
            'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
            'referer': 'https://google.com',
            'user-agent': user_agent,
        }

        r = create_request(url, headers)
        if r is None:
            logging.warning('Empty Request')
            return
        if r.status_code == 200:
            html = r.text
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
            # Name
            name = get_name(soup)

            # Location
            location = get_location(soup)

            # Review
            avg_review = get_average_review(soup)

            # Sales
            sales = get_sales(soup)

            # Admirers
            admirers = get_admirers(soup)

            # Rating
            rating = get_rating(soup)

            # Review Count
            review_count = get_review_count(soup)

            # Etsy Since
            year = get_etsy_since(soup)

            # Storing the data in DB and updating status
            print('Storing Data')
            logging.info('Storing Data')
            store_parsed(url, name, location, avg_review, sales, admirers, rating, review_count, year)
            print('Data Stored')
            logging.info('Data Stored')
            print('=============END====================')
    except Exception as ex:
        crash_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%m:%S")
        crash_string = "".join(traceback.format_exception(etype=type(ex), value=ex, tb=ex.__traceback__))
        exception_string = '[' + crash_date + '] - ' + crash_string + '\n'
        print(exception_string)
    finally:
        return None
```

Comment: `After some X period of time script just stops working` → Sounds like your global IP is banned at scraped side?.. `I also ran the script without proxies and it seemed to work` →Because banned proxy IP is changed? ;) And just a useless advice: In your case IO waiting is a bottle neck,so  async may be more effective and simple than multiprocessing

Comment: @rzlvmp I am having more issues with proxies. I am using Storm proxies that give new IP in each request.

Which IO waiting is here? I am using MySQL only. can you explain how async will help here? any example?

Comment: `Which IO waiting is here?` → waiting of response from remote server is a slower part in the script. Async is able to switch between requests waiting for response in single process. `can you explain how async will help here?` → Async sounds like a technology that pretty fit to your needs, but it not solve the problem. That was just an extra reccommendation regardless question. `I am having more issues with proxies` → hmmm, sounds like proxy is a problem? did you check limitations for this service?

Comment: @rzlvmp Yes and I am getting no timeout error either

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what is Storm proxy and how it works. Looks like that is non reproducible  environment problem. It is hard to guess what may cause this behavior

Comment: My issue is that script just gets frozen forever, how do I deal with this situation?

Comment: `My issue is that script just gets frozen forever` → If script gets frozen after scraping is complete, probably you have to collect results of all processes and manually close parent process when child processes complete? Here is no multiprocess part in the example code to be able check how it works `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`

Comment: @rzlvmp NO it freezes in the middle.  Should I include the part fo the code dealing with multiprocessing?

Comment: `Should I include the part fo the code dealing with multiprocessing?` → at least that will be better than nothing

Comment: @rzlvmp Added the relevant code.

Comment: couldn't find any visible issues in code `¯\_(ツ)_/¯`